# Wordpress-Loop: PHP-code is not working

Tags: wordpress

i'm currently struggling making my wordpress-loop working properly. I guess the error is in the IF-request. Could anyone please debug and optimize these few lines of PHP? I'm very interested in learning proper coding so don't hesitate to give me some further advices! ;-) 
Would be amazing! All the best, enjoy your weekend!!!

```
<?php


?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Start body -->

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<!-- Hier geht der Wrapper auf-->                                              
<div class="wrapper">

<!-- Get Logo -->
<?php get_template_part( 'logo' ); ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

<!-- Wordpress verbieten, <p>-Tags zu setzen -->  

<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>



    <!-- T H E   L O O P -->  


    <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="article-content" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <div class="article-thumb">

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <div class="theid"><?php the_ID(); ?></div>

    <?php if (in_category( "28" )){
        echo '<a href="';
        echo '#';
        echo '" target="_blank"> link</a>';

        }

    else { echo 'Hi!'; ?>


    <!-- Close article-thumb -->
        </div>

    <!-- Close article-content -->

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


    <!-- /T H E   L O O P -->  



<!-- Clear -->    

<div class="clear"></div>



<?php else: ?>
<h2>No posts to display</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


<!-- bottomnav -->

<div class="bottomnav"><a class="super next"><?php posts_nav_link(' / ','Zurück','Weitere Projekte'); ?></a></div>



<!-- Infinite Scroll -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.wrapper').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        finished: undefined,
        finishedMsg: "End.",
        img: "http://www.injuvik.de/wp-content/themes/injuvik/img/pfeilnachunten.png",
        msg: null,
        msgText: "Loading..",
        selector: null,
        speed: 'fast',
        start: undefined

        },
    navSelector: "div.bottomnav",
    nextSelector: "div.bottomnav a:last", 
    itemSelector: "div.wrapper div.article-content",
    animate: false
    });
</script>



</div>

<!-- toggle class on click -->

<script>
$('body').on('click', 'div.article-content', function(){
$( this ).toggleClass( "bigger" );
});
</script>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Well does it work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add to the end of the code

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also change:

```
echo 'Hi!';
}
/>
```

to

```
echo 'Hi!';
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure you're on a page that has content by default from wordpress? like a blog page, or category page, etc? what's the name of the file?

Comment: please add this line to wp-config.php or edit it:
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: Could it be, that there's some more buggy php-code? I've edited my question and posted the whole index.php-code in there...

Comment: youre missing : else { echo 'Hi!'; ?> here, you must add a }

Comment: Like this? Still not working.

 else { 
  echo 'Hi!'; 
  } ?>

Comment: remove 

<?php else: ?>
<h2>No posts to display</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Check This one out ! I just used it from Wordpress Documentation [Wordpress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

```
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php if ( in_category( '28' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="post-cat-three">
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="post">
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

AWWW!

The solution was so simple! I just had two else-commands inside my index.php.

Thank you Guys!